# Android - how listener system event?

Tags: android, events, button

How get event click button "all apps"?

http://imgsrv.worldstart.com/images/ct-images/2012/05/kevin_android_animation_1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the documentation for the complete list of key events here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

As it stands, this isn't supported by any API level, presumably because as far as widget and app development goes there is no reason to detect an app menu click. It may be possible with some lower-level hack but not from the stock Android SDK.